# Unity facebook SDK sharing on facebook

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I have some problems with using the FB.Feed dialog of the facebook unity SDK. I can share everything without a hitch, but the problem comes when a user has posted something and wants to use the facebook "share" button (on facebook.com) to share his post.

The only thing that the user can share is the page that is linked to in the FB.Feed. It is not possible to share the actual description containing his score and difficulty, as we want the user to be able to share his score and not the facebook page in the link.

Is there anything is missing that would enable the user to share his actual score instead of the linked page?

(Disregard the strings in the linkName, Caption, and Description as they are just placeholders)

```
FB.Feed(
            link: "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Retris-Reversed-Tetris/1570129109911797?fref=ts",
            linkName: "I just scored " + GameManager.CurrentScore + " points in Retris on " + GameManager.CurrentDifficulty + "!",
            linkCaption: "Checkout my awesome score on " + GameManager.CurrentDifficulty + " difficulty!",
            linkDescription: "I just scored " + GameManager.CurrentScore + " points on " + GameManager.CurrentDifficulty + "!",
            picture: "http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah130/Redomex/logo512_zpskocz8jlk.png"
          );
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open Graph to share structured stories.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/sharing#opengraphcustomstories

Answer (score -1):

i didn't see the callback method, maybe ...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Feed#examples